# Paginação com o codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paginação

será que algum dos senhores poderam me ajudar a encontrar o erro neste codigo de paginação com o codeigniter. ele imprime os links da forma correta, porém ele mostra mais itens do que deveria por pagina, e quando troco de pagina ele mostra os mesmos itens, ou seja, os links parecem funcionar mais a paginação não, alguém ajuda?

Segue o código

$this->load->library('pagination');

```
    $maximo = 10;

    $config['base_url'] = 'Busca/pesquisa';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all_results('produtos');
    $config['per_page'] = $maximo;
    $config ['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $config['first_link'] = FALSE;


    $config['next_link'] = 'Próximo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';


    $config['last_link'] = FALSE;


    $config['prev_link'] = 'Anterior';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<b style="color:#23527C;">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '&nbsp;';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);


    $paginas = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data=[            
        "categorias" => $query_categorias,
        "paginas"  =>$paginas,
          ];

     $data_content = array(
        'content' => $this->load->view('exibe_busca/index', $data, true)
    );

    $this->load->view('layouts/template', $data_content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não dar para indentificar o erro só olhando essa parte do código no controller, mas possivelmente o erro deve está relacionado ao valor que o método **count_all_results** está retornando, que deve está diferenre do total de itens que você quer exibir, somando todos os resultados por página, ou também, o erro pode ser o offset que você está usando para filtrar os dados de intervalo a intervalo na tabela no banco de dados que deve ter algum erro.

Aqui vou mostrar um exemplo de como eu implemento paginação no CI, para que você possa usar como base para corrigir você mesmo seu erro, já que não consigo indentifica-ló olhando o trecho de código que você forneceu.

1° Para poder reaproveitar o código e ficar mais organizado usando menos código no método do controller, vou criar um arquivo de configuração de paginação localizado na pasta **config/**, cujo o nome padrão dele é pagination.php com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php

$config['num_links'] = 10;

$config['per_page'] = 20;

$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination float-right border-rounded-5">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

$config['first_link'] = 'Primeiro';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="first-pagination">';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['last_link'] = '&Uacute;ltimo';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="last-pagination">';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

// $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next-pagination">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

// $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev-pagination">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="current-pagination">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

Obs.: utilizando essa arquivo **config/pagination.php**, todos os locais onde você utilizar o library pagination os valores definidos nele ficaram pre-definidos como padrão para a configuração da paginação.

2° No código abaixo vou mostrar como eu implemento o método do controller da página onde será exibido a páginação:

```
public function listar()
{

    //$limit Equivalente a sua variável $maximo
    $limit = 10;
    //$offset 3° segmento da URL que serve como base da paginação intervalada dos registros do banco de dados
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

    //Recupera os dados no banco de dados de acordo com o limite difinido de dados a serem retornados e começando partir do registro $offset
    $lista = $this->produto_model->retrieve($limit, $offset);

    // Carregando a biblioteca pagination
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    //Configurando a url base da paginação
    $configPagination['base_url'] = base_url() . 'usuario/listar';
    //Total de registros para que se possa gerar os links da paginação
    $configPagination['total_rows'] = $this->usuario_model->count();

    //Setar as configurações
    $this->pagination->initialize($configPagination);

    //Gerar paginação
    $pagination = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $dados = array(
        'data_list' => $lista,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    );

    $this->load->view('produtos/listar', $dados);

}
```

Comment: Obrigado Yure Pereira, concerteza irá me ajudar muito a entender, obrigado mesmo.